# Push data from database to flask web app and Android device

Tags: android, database, flask, sqlalchemy, iot

How can I show real time database changes in a flask website?
Like on_update and on_insert, the data will be pushed to the website for the user to see.

I want to get alert from an IOT device and insert it to the database and the users who are subbed to that device should get the real-time alerts.
So I thought

```
>IOT detects
>HTTP POST to database
>Flask App detects the database change
>push to clients on web app and android
```

I made a web app that queries the DB with flask-sqlalchemy but thats it, these are supposed to be real-time alerts! I'm so frustrated it's been a week. I am going nowhere and I feel so lost now.

```
>polling
>web sockets
>SSE
>flask sse
>use AJAX
>use JQUERY
```

HHHOOOOOWWWWW?????? Most of the examples are for chat apps, and I see NO method where you listen to database changes and send it to clients ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way to implement this is using an event SaaS like [pusher.com](https://pusher.com/). This should get you set up in no time. They have examples for many different languages and it should fit your need perfectly.

You mention that you see so many chat-apps as examples. This is pretty normal as they are almost the "hello-world" of event-based systems. And that's exactly what you are looking for. An *event* happens and you want to *trigger* something on that event.

For chats, the event is: "The user entered a message" and the triggered action is: "Display it to every connected/subscribed user".

Next to a hosted service like pusher.com, you can roll your own. All the required technology are free and open standards. You could use websockets or WebRTC for this. Websockets is easier but it's trickier if you have *many* open channels. On the other hand, WebRTC scales but it's a bit more complicated to set up. But you won't need video or audio which makes it easier.

You mention "polling" and I am not sure whether you mean "normal" polling or long-polling as in [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). That is of course an option. It is the easiest solution, but not the cleanest.

SSE seems like a valid option as well. Although I have no personal experience with it yet. But it seems like it's designed for this use-case.

AJAX and jQuery are less related. AJAX is just an umbrella term for programming using `XmlHTTPRequest` and is used in all solutions mentioned above. jQuery is just a JS framework and is completely unrelated to the task.

long story short: All your mentioned options allow you to do this. I would suggest looking at pusher.com to get started. And their examples have exactly what you need. Their free plan is already really generous for personal projects. If your application outgrows the free plan you can either pay, or roll your own solution.

Comment: Hey thanks man. Your answer does feel like a push in the right direction, no pun intended. I will definitely go for pusher.com and when I have a better understanding I would want to switch it to SSE because as you said, it's designed for this use case. I really don't want to use sockets because it will be a wasted bidirectional connection, low latency is cool but I won't be getting alerts every second. I think I should have mentioned this is a IOT project for flash flood detection. Surely if I'm able to deploy this I'll send you a link to my web app. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds interesting. And yes, the wasted connections are a big downside of websockets. In fact I was not aware of SSE until I investigated your question. I see use-cases for myself as well for this.

Comment: Even I wasn't aware of SSE until I read an article on Medium comparing sockets, long polling and SSE, here's the link : ` https://codeburst.io/polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket-how-to-choose-the-right-one-1859e4e13bd9 ` As it happens, very few people know of SSE but it's more suitable to use than Web Sockets.